# Byte array conversion

Tags: javascript, image

I have this code in c# :

```
byte[] byteArrayPng;
using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayTiff))
using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Bitmap.FromStream(inStream).Save(outStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    byteArrayPng = outStream.ToArray();
}
```

I want to convert an array of byte (.tif image) into an array of byte (.png image). I get the first array form an API.

With the new array (.png image), I can display the image in  because the tiff format is not supported by browsers.

Is it possible to do the same in Angular/TypeScript?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? How is the file available to JavaScript? Is it loaded from a URL? Is it loaded into a Canvas? It's certainly possible to load an image of almost any valid format into a Canvas and convert that into a PNG.

Comment: I get the array of byte (tiff image) from an API. And, i want to convert it to another image format. 
With the new array, I can display the image in <img></img> because the tiff format is not supported by browsers.

Comment: PNG is based on Zlib so doing this on the client-side will be a hassle, you'll certainly need WebAssembly. You should do it on the server side to save bandwidth and use efficient image processing libraries. Really though, you should do it in advance and store PNGs instead of TIFFs…

Comment: Actually, the easiest thing to do may be to render the TIFF to a canvas directly, if it is uncompressed (it's just a list of pixel values). Then you can use the native canvas API to generate a PNG, if that's still needed.